# Disk not available for use under Linux on Sun hardware

Tags: linux, hard-drive, sun

We have a Sun 4140 running Linux (CentOS 5.5).  A disk failed in a software RAID-1 array.  We powered off the system and added a two new disks to empty slots in the chassis (we couldn't simply replace the failed disk due to some GRUB misconfiguration).  Upon booting the system back up, we went to configure the new disks and add them to the array, but it wasn't found under the `/dev` subsystem.

The disk was found during booting (output of `dmesg`):

```
Vendor: HP        Model: EG0146FAWHU       Rev: HPDE
Type:   Direct-Access                      ANSI SCSI revision: 05
Vendor: HP        Model: EG0146FAWHU       Rev: HPDE
Type:   Direct-Access                      ANSI SCSI revision: 05
```

Output of `udevinfo`:

```
[root@host ~]# udevinfo -a -p /sys/bus/scsi/devices/0\:1\:4\:0/

looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0f.0/0000:04:00.0/host0/target0:1:4/0:1:4:0':
  KERNEL=="0:1:4:0"
  SUBSYSTEM=="scsi"
  SYSFS{dh_state}=="detached"
  SYSFS{ioerr_cnt}=="0x0"
  SYSFS{iodone_cnt}=="0x3"
  SYSFS{iorequest_cnt}=="0x3"
  SYSFS{iocounterbits}=="32"
  SYSFS{timeout}=="60"
  SYSFS{state}=="running"
  SYSFS{rev}=="HPDE"
  SYSFS{model}=="EG0146FAWHU     "
  SYSFS{vendor}=="HP      "
  SYSFS{scsi_level}=="6"
  SYSFS{type}=="0"
  SYSFS{queue_type}=="none"
  SYSFS{queue_depth}=="1"
  SYSFS{device_blocked}=="0"
  SYSFS{level}=="Hidden"
```

What do we need to do to make the disks be recognized?  Any other things that we need to try?

**EDIT**

Here is the output of `/proc/scsi/scsi`:

```
Host: scsi0 Channel: 01 Id: 04 Lun: 00
  Vendor: HP       Model: EG0146FAWHU      Rev: HPDE
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI SCSI revision: 05
Host: scsi0 Channel: 01 Id: 05 Lun: 00
  Vendor: HP       Model: EG0146FAWHU      Rev: HPDE
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI SCSI revision: 05
```

Here are all of the drives and partitions found in `/dev`:

```
-bash-3.2$ ls -l /dev/sd* /dev/hd*
ls: /dev/hd*: No such file or directory
brw-r----- 1 root disk 8,  0 Jun 22 22:37 /dev/sda
brw-r----- 1 root disk 8,  1 Jun 22 22:37 /dev/sda1
brw-r----- 1 root disk 8,  2 Jun 22 22:37 /dev/sda2
brw-r----- 1 root disk 8, 16 Jun 22 22:37 /dev/sdb
brw-r----- 1 root disk 8, 17 Jun 22 22:37 /dev/sdb1
brw-r----- 1 root disk 8, 18 Jun 22 22:37 /dev/sdb2
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you see anything from `cat /proc/scsi/scsi`? That will show something similar to the `dmesg` output you listed above. What happens if you run `fdisk -l`? You should be able to get the drive device names from that.

```
Disk /dev/sda: 85.8 GB, 85899345920 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 10443 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
.
.
.
Disk /dev/sdb: 42.9 GB, 42949672960 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 5221 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
.
.
.
Disk /dev/sdc: 128.8 GB, 128849018880 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 15665 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
```

Comment: I didn't include the output of `cat /proc/scsi/scsi` originally as it didn't have any different output than `dmesg` did.  I have added that detail as well as a listing of all drives found in `/dev`.

Comment: What about `fdisk -l`?

Comment: `fdisk -l` does not return any new information.  It is just a repeat of what I have already provided.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this server has a hardware raid controller in it (at least all the 4140s I have around do). In a typical configuration, you'd let the raid controller take care of the RAID1, which would be presented to the OS as a single volume. In your configuration, I'm guessing that the two drives are configured on the RAID controller as two RAID0 arrays. To get the third and fourth drives to appear, you'll likely need to go into the RAID bios and configure them as two, single-member RAID0 arrays, which you should be able to see from the OS after a reboot.

Comment: The server does have a RAID controller, but it is not configured for use.  When I opened the controller configuration upon booting, zero RAID groups were defined.  Since the server was built with software RAID I need to keep in that direction as a rebuild is not appropriate at this time.